# wxPython in thread can not be shut down without error

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

I am new to wxPython, so I basically just copied something that will display a tray icon and made it a thread:

```
import wx
import wx.adv
from threading import Thread

TRAY_TOOLTIP = 'System Tray Demo'
TRAY_ICON = 'icon.png'


class Main(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        self.app = App()
        self.app.MainLoop()


def create_menu_item(menu, label, func):
    item = wx.MenuItem(menu, -1, label)
    menu.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, func, id=item.GetId())
    menu.Append(item)
    return item


class TaskBarIcon(wx.adv.TaskBarIcon):
    def __init__(self, frame):
        self.frame = frame
        super(TaskBarIcon, self).__init__()
        self.set_icon(TRAY_ICON)
        self.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_TASKBAR_LEFT_DOWN, self.on_left_down)

    def CreatePopupMenu(self):
        menu = wx.Menu()
        create_menu_item(menu, 'Exit', self.on_exit)
        return menu

    def set_icon(self, path):
        icon = wx.Icon(wx.Bitmap(path))
        self.SetIcon(icon, TRAY_TOOLTIP)

    def on_left_down(self, event):
        print('Tray icon was left-clicked.')

    def on_exit(self, event):
        wx.CallAfter(self.Destroy)
        self.frame.Close()


class App(wx.App):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.App.__init__(self, False)

    def OnInit(self):
        frame = wx.Frame(None)
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        TaskBarIcon(frame)
        return True
```

from my main thread, which is a very long running service, I am starting the GUI thread, activating the scheduler and checking if it should run like so:

```
gui = trayIcon.Main()
gui.start()
schedule.every(60).minutes.do(main)

while gui.is_alive():
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)

# if this is reached the gui thread has terminated and the program should shut down
sys.exit()
```

It works as it should be: When the exit item in the tray icon menu is clicked, the GUI thread shuts down, is then no longer detected in the while loop of the main thread and sys.exit() is called.
Unfortunately, wxPython then shows an error dialog with the following text:

> ---
>
> ### wxWidgets Debug Alert
>
> ....\src\common\socket.cpp(767): assert "wxIsMainThread()" failed in
>   wxSocketBase::IsInitialized(): unsafe to call from other threads [in
>   thread 1284] Do you want to stop the program? You can also choose
>   [Cancel] to suppress further warnings.

How can I shut down the GUI correctly or at least suppress this warning? After it the program quits as it should be, although I suspect suppressing the message would leave a memory leak of some kind.

Thanks in advance

Taxel

Comment: putting the mainloop() in another thread is generally bad practice. Sending commands to the UI from child threads causes all kinds of problems in wx. It's best to put the mainloop in the main thread and use child threads to process tasks in the background if you need them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it looks like you have set it up backwards. The main thread should always be the wxPython one. MainLoop should not be called inside a thread. Instead you should let wxPython be in control and run your long running thread inside of it.

Then when your long running task is finished, you can use a thread-safe method, like `wx.CallAfter` to tell wxPython that it is time to exit. Since wxPython is the one in control, it can close itself correctly.

Here are some articles that might help you:

- https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/
- https://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks